# Is it professional to question my boss about their constantly interrupting me?

Tags: management, communication, micro-management

I’m in my school’s co-op program and the last placement I was a solo developer. There were communication issues between me and my boss and I would like to avoid such in the future. Every hour my boss would unexpectedly come into my room and ask for updates, demonstrations and poke around with the code. He explained he didn't know programming but could read the English in the code and would tell me to change it if something didn't look right to him, and this usually had a negative effect on the code.

I had a meeting with him and his boss to try and resolve them. (it wasn't my idea to bring in his boss, it was theirs) I suggested that we arrange a schedule where I give him updates and demonstrations and anything else required. I phrased it to focus on the benefits to him: I could better prepare a concise presentation and make sure I have running code to demonstrate. To me the benefits would have been I’m not frequently getting interrupted. Was this a reasonable idea?

My boss’s boss said no to this, explaining “People could unexpectedly walk up to me and ask me questions so I think it’s fair if they do that to you too”. I found the reasoning a bit odd because just because someone does it to him doesn't mean it's a good fit for my job.

I had a meeting with my school’s co-op adviser, and told him about this. He told me that I had to be adaptable and that if my boss decides it’s necessary to interrupt, that’s his choice to make. I agree with this, but it also seems like an issue never got resolved because nothing changed and now much productivity was lost.

Aside from whether it being a good idea or not, was it rude to ask or could I have phrased it differently?

UPDATE: I thought it was customary on the stackexchange network to explain down votes and close votes. What is wrong with this question? I know it says "opinion based", but how are questions like "How should I deal with an employee who has slept with my wife?" or "Is it rude to leave an interview early if you have already made your decision?" not opinion based?

Comment: Reasonable request.  Unreasonable answer.  But that is the answer.

Comment: Wasn't this exact same question asked a day or so ago, except it was SQL not English?

Comment: That behavior is bizarre - it indicates one of three {3} things:  (1) Your boss does not trust you - he or she believes you are goofing off or not working at the expected pace, (2) Your boss is physically attracted to you, (3) Your boss is attempting to learn what you are doing because he or she has to take over when you are done (i.e. they cannot afford a perm developer).

Comment: @Kilisi and joe yes I had posted this question before and it was poorly received so I deleted it and rewrote it. Why do you ask?

Comment: @KimC Rather than delete a question and post a new one, it's best to try to edit the original question.  Unfortunately, this one has also been poorly received for being primarily opinion based.  Perhaps try to distil it down to something that can be answered more definitively.  Questions and answers on SE are meant to be a knowledge base that can be useful not just for the original poster, but for future visitors to the site.

Comment: @JaneS I would take this to meta but don't have enough rep. So for the time being, could you please tell me how to make the question less opinion based, or at least specify which elements make it opinion based? Since how to act in the workplace isn't a science, I believe any questions pertaining to it are opinion based.

Comment: @JaneS "try to distil it down to something that can be answered more definitively" with 5 comments and 3 down votes before yours why hasn't anyone explained what is wrong with the question? I'm still waiting for Kilsi and Joe to reply...

Comment: @KimC Rather than ask "Should I have...", a better, less opinion based question to ask is "Is it professional to question my boss about their constantly interrupting me?"  Then you can decide how you choose to act.

Comment: If you want to discuss the reasoning behind close votesm take that question to the Workplace Meta area. Please be aware that "but the other guy got away with it" is not by itself sufficient justification. Reality is fractal.

Comment: @keshlam I don't have enough reputation to go to meta. And the expectation is with so many votes that at least someone should comment why.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> Aside from whether it being a good idea or not, was it ***rude*** to ask or could I have phrased it differently?

The term 'rude' is subject to opinion and perhaps not productively what you ought to be evaluating (unless your position description distinctly entails *not being rude*). ;)

Focusing on **productivity** will serve you well. See [How can I be assertive without being rude or offensive?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6853/how-can-i-be-assertive-without-being-rude-or-offensive) for more ideas.
My favourite sage advice:

> Focus on listening and understanding things which you consider wrong
>   or critiques/rebuttals to your positions. Concentrate on understanding
>   the opposite viewpoints, regardless of how wrong, rather than thinking
>   through how to best respond immediately.

And if you still feel ill-equipped to devise your scale of rudeness, take heart... Undoubtedly, we all fall short according to this article:
http://theweek.com/articles/460821/how-avoid-being-rude-according-100yearold-etiquette-rules. =)

And remember...
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I agree it is better to be assertive than someone else's monkey.